# Is it possible to dynamically change tooltip on c3 charts?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

When you generate a c3 chart, you can define a lot of properties ,among other also a tooltip, as seen here:

```
generateData = () => {
  const x = randomNR(0, 100);
  const y = randomNR(0, 100);
  const together = x + y;

  return {
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', x],
        ['data2', y],
      ],
      type: 'donut',
    },
    tooltip: {
      format: {
        value: function() {
          return `${x} + ${y} = ${together}`
        }
      }
    },
    donut: {
      title: `Tooltip not getting updated`
    }
  }
};
```

However, when the chart is generated, we can only load the new data property. I was wondering if it's possible to update the tooltip as well?
Here's my case (it's only for illustrative purposes): https://plnkr.co/edit/8PrbjVqhS9BBYpSbZmkM?p=preview

As you can see, when the data is updated, the tooltip is no longer representing the correct values.

Comment: Sure, the issue seems to be that the function just uses the first tuple of of x, y and together, so for example moving x, y and together outside of generateData, or making a closure with x, y and together global to the closure or such will resolve the issue. I don't know how to share a plnkr unfortunately but yeah that will do it.

Comment: Yeah I figured this much, perhaps it's my fault for not provide a wider context, I have several instances of such graphs scattered around the app (they can be dynamically added or removed), so doing this globally just causes the values to be overwritten, sadly. I'd need a more cleaner way to change these values

Comment: Right but a closure should be fine for you? I still don't know how to share, but something like... wait I'll post as an answer

Comment: I've actually solved this way easier, using the ARROW FUNCTION expression: https://codesandbox.io/s/9jx9958v5p

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?

```
function randomNR(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function f() {
  let x;
  let y;
  let together;
  return () => {
    x = randomNR(0, 100);
    y = randomNR(0, 100);
    together = x + y;
    return {
      data: {
        columns: [
          ['data1', x],
          ['data2', y],
        ],
        type: 'donut',
      },
      tooltip: {
        format: {
          value: function() {
            return `${x} + ${y} = ${together}`
          }
        }
      },
      donut: {
        title: `Tooltip not getting updated`
      }
    }
  };
}

const myGen = f();

const chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  ...myGen()
});

setTimeout(function() {
  // HOW TO UPDATE THE TOOLTIP HERE?
  chart.load(myGen().data);
}, 2500);
```